# Symfony - How to validate configuration node against another node value?

Tags: validation, symfony, configuration, traits

In my Configuration.php I have a structure as following:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
  $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
  $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');

  $rootNode
    ->children()
      ->scalarNode('class')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
      ->arrayNode('social_network')
        ->children()
          ->arrayNode('facebook')
            ->validate()
              ->ifTrue(function($node) {

                // my logic to validate if the 'class' specified implements my trait

              })
              ->thenInvalid('You must use XXXXXX trait in your class.')
            ->end()
            ->children()
              ->scalarNode('app_id')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
              ->scalarNode('secret')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->end()
          ->end()
        ->end()
      ->end()
    ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

I need to check if the specified class implement a specific trait part of my bundle.

How can I read the value of the `class` within the `function($node)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question so I decided to experiment and see how it could be done. Usually, one would only put more general validation, which is why I guess you can't directly do it within the `getConfigTreeBuilder` function. Or at least I couldn't find a way. You can try doing `function($node) use($rootNode)` but you can't get the value of the `node`. So even if you try to do `$rootNode->getNode('class')` within the scope of your anonymous function, you wouldn't be able to get the actual value.

What you could do, on the other hand, is to go to your `Extension` class (located in `DependencyInjection` dir) and do the validation there. Something like this should do the work:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $class = $config['class'];

    // Apply your logic here...
    if(!$this->checkForTrait($class, 'myTrait')) {
        throw new \ErrorException("The class ".$class." should implement myTrait!");
    }

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}

private function checkForTrait($class, $trait)
{
    $class = new \ReflectionClass($class);
    $traits = $class->getTraitNames(); // returns an array of all trait names being currently used in that class.
    return in_array($trait, $traits);
}
```

I don't know if this is considered as "best practice", so if anybody has a better solution, please point it out :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to call `validate()` method inside `scalarNode('class')` node. Take a look:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('class')
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->validate()
                    ->ifTrue(function ($value) {
                        // my logic to validate if the 'class' specified implements my trait

                        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($value);
                        $traitsNames = $reflection->getTraitNames();

                        return false === \in_array('myTrait', $traitsNames, true);
                    })
                    ->thenInvalid('You must use XXXXXX trait in your class.')
                ->end()
            ->end()
            ->arrayNode('social_network')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('facebook')
                        ->children()
                            ->scalarNode('app_id')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                            ->scalarNode('secret')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

In this way validation is done per the scalar `class` node. The `$value` is value of `class` node, so it's name of your class.

The rest:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($value);
$traitsNames = $reflection->getTraitNames();

return false === \in_array('myTrait', $traitsNames, true);
```

it's just a piece of php code that verifies if the trait is implemented.